# How to get sysdate of one instance from another instance in oracle 11g

Tags: database, oracle11g

We have 2 instances for a database. Both have 20 minutes time difference. Need to get the sysdate of particular instance in runtime. I will get the instance_ID and instance_name. With these parameters how can I get sysdate of that instance? Please let me know if I'm not clear.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Following command gives sysdate from remote server pointed by database_link:

```
select sysdate from dual@database_link;
```

Answer (score 0):

As I remember, this thing should work. Create a function, with returns `sysdate`:

```
create or replace function instance_date return date is
begin
  return sysdate;
end;
```

Call it from another instance via dblink:

```
select instance_date@remote_db from dual;
```